# Scratch ORG is not opening in browser

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

[image]
my scratch org is not opening in browser, vs code just display the url of the org in Terminal I am using chrome and its my default browser as well.

Comment: try setting default to some other browser and then test

Comment: Tried 3 browsers, same results